# How do I 'left-center' align content on all devices to remain responsiveness with css?

Tags: html, css, text

I have a title and paragraph of text. It is currently left aligned (screenshot 1). I would like to move the title and paragraph to the middle of the page, compress the with of the paragraph to make a neat rectangle but also keep it left-aligned. I want to design this so that the title and text maintains this layout (screenshot 2) on different devices and text does not get cut off, say, on a mobile phone.

This is what my page with text looks like:

[image: Screenshot 1]

This is what I want my page to look like:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Flexbox.

```css
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }
  .child {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60%;
  }
  h1, p {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut diam sit amet sapien congue sodales vel a purus. Sed eget libero et sem rhoncus dignissim tempus nec lectus. Vivamus varius ullamcorper dui, nec placerat tellus laoreet sit amet. Sed aliquam augue enim, et scelerisque ex volutpat sed. Pellentesque pretium metus diam, ut vulputate tortor hendrerit et. Nullam luctus magna eget nibh pharetra semper. Nunc nisi metus, mollis eget felis id, tristique dapibus arcu. Pellentesque efficitur tortor auctor elit molestie porta. In nec vulputate lorem. Morbi imperdiet gravida sapien vitae varius. Nulla id congue augue. Donec pretium tellus at felis egestas consectetur. Sed efficitur, ante eget semper consequat, lacus ligula varius diam, tristique lobortis lectus elit eget arcu. Nullam et ex pellentesque, lobortis orci sed, pellentesque ante. Fusce ac ex sapien. Aliquam aliquet odio eu auctor eleifend.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Best answer awarded!

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to view your picture.

But since you would like to move stuff, you can consider using `margin-left` or `padding-left` in your `<style></style>`

compress the width of the paragraph to make a neat rectangle, you can consider using `width = 100%` or using `fixed width respective to the rectangle you want to align to.`

to prevent text being cut off, you can set the `position = relative;` or `position= fixed;` play around with it to see what fits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you would include your html css as well.  But I guess you could do pretty easy by using margins.
For instance

```
   p{
     Margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mycontent">
   I'm so centered it's crazy!
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .wrapper {
      display: block;
  }
  .mycontent {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 768px;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the above answer, you can simply use `margin-left` or `padding-left` with a specified parameter, and then call [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to specify these alignments across different device parameters.

Ex.:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
h1, p {
    margin-left: 5%;
    }
}
```